# Angular post request ends with 400

Tags: angular, post, bad-request

When I am sending the same post request in Postman all is okey.
But with Angular I got 400 Bad Request
Please help me to understand what is the problem because I have no ideas

**http.service.ts**

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Auth} from './auth';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
 
@Injectable()
export class HttpService{
 
    constructor(private http: Http){ }
     
    postData(obj: Auth){
        const body = JSON.stringify(obj);
         
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;' });
         
        return this.http.post('https://integrationapi.net/rest/user/sessionid', body, { headers: headers })
                        .map((resp:Response)=>resp.json())
                        .catch((error:any) =>{return Observable.throw(error);}); 
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Auth} from './auth';
import { HttpService} from './http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpService],
})
export class AppComponent {
  auth: Auth=new Auth();



  res : string = '';

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService){}

    ngOnInit() {

     this.auth.login = '********';
    this.auth.password = '********';

    console.log(this.auth);

       this.httpService.postData(this.auth).subscribe((data) => this.res);
    }
}
```

**auth.ts**

```js
export class Auth {
 login    : string;
 password : string;
}
```

Comment: A 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules. And in your code , you dont need headers , because default header of put and post in angular in application/json , try remove it

Comment: and also , you dont need `new Auth()` . auth:Auth is enough

Comment: and change `class Auth` to `interface Auth`

Comment: Thanks

But after changes with Auth to interface and 'auth:Auth'

I have got another Error
http://i.piccy.info/i9/3f58503ac9dad45c19860f6475e05b32/1496304056/67686/1150501/Untitled.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Change your component to

```
   var auth:Auth[] = [
    {login:'...',password:'..' }  //put it outside class
    ]


 ngOnInit() {

        this.httpService.postData(auth).subscribe((data) => this.res);
    }
```